# Laravel 5.4 Anchor Link

Tags: hyperlink, routes, anchor, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

This question may be a pretty quite noob question but I have searched a lot about it and still haven't find the answer.

First of all, here's the code of my route:

```
Route::get('/', 'MainController@home');
```

Then, here's my nav bar.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="{{url('/')}}">Our History</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="{{url('/')}}">Our Politics</a></li>
</ul>
```

As yu can see, when someone click on "Our History" or "Our Politics" it wil redirect to the Home Page. All this code is in "app.blade.php" file.

Now, all the information about "Our History" and "Our Politics" is in "home.blade.php" file and it's something like this (Notice "name=1" for Our History and "name=2" for Our Politics"):

```
<div name="1" class="medium-padding text-center top-space">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <p>Information</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <p>Information</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's almost the same code for "Our Politics.

So ¿How can I make that when someone click on the nav "Our History" or "Our Politics" it redirect to (/) but to the div "name=1"?

Yes, I know you don't "debug" code for other but I search "Laravel Anchor Link" on Google and read every link of the 14 results pages and found nothing that coud help me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps someone. I found the answer: adding an "id".

On the navbar:

```
<div name="1" id="1" class="medium-padding text-center top-space">
```

On the div:

```
<li><a href="{{url('/#1')}}">Our History</a></li>
```

:)